# Connecting Widgets

Tags: java, gwt

My project is about drawing ER Diagrams, for this I am using GWT. For now i have most of the frontend working. Now I want to have lines connecting two widgets to create a relationship between the entities and attributes. For that I want to create 4 corner points to which the lines can connect (Technology something similar to EDrawMax or DIA).

example picture
[example picture http://www.cs.uofs.edu/~sudhakaras2/Example.jpg](http://www.cs.uofs.edu/~sudhakaras2/Example.jpg)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
<sub>(source: [googlecode.com](http://gwt-diagrams.googlecode.com/files/screenshot.gif))</sub>

If the corner stuff is optional, [gwt-diagrams](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-diagrams/) might be a good and clean option. Check the demo [here](http://kolos.math.uni.lodz.pl/~balon/gwt-diagrams-demo/).